# Timer stuck in alert state

Tags: watchos

For the past few weeks, I have been unable to use the Timer app on my Apple Watch Series 3. When I open it, it shows the buttons "cancel|resume" with the last-run time. If I force-quit and reopen, it's still stuck on "cancel|resume". If I reboot, it works once and then gets stuck again.

Here's a linked screenshot of a Tweet of someone else reporting this issue.

[image: Timer 6:34 / 01:00 / Cancel | Resume]

Anyone else have this problem, or know how to fix it?

watchOS version: 6.1 (17S84)

Comment: What watchOS version?  I'm assuming you've restarted the Watch?

Comment: @fsb edited question to include those details, thanks!

Comment: It seems this is a common problem with watchOS 6.  Personally, I've never experienced it.  So far I can't find a solution, only workarounds (use Siri to set the timer, force close the app, etc.).

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue on my Series 2 watch, running watchOS 6.1